# Copy constructor alters std::string

Tags: c++, string, copy-constructor

Can someone please explain to me what is happening here? (I'm not familiar enough with C++).

I have a `std::string`, which starts with 4 `int32_t` added by using a binary stringstream and calling the method `write()`.

When I do this, `index`, `type` and `tag` (3 of the 4 int32-ts) are correct.

```
SocketInfo currentSocketInfo;
currentSocketInfo.header.reserve(_headerLength);
int iResult = recv(socket, &currentSocketInfo.header[0], _headerLength, 0);

auto headerIntPtr = reinterpret_cast<const int32_t*>(currentSocketInfo.header.c_str());

int32_t index = headerIntPtr[1];
int32_t type = headerIntPtr[2];
int32_t tag = headerIntPtr[3];

appendCurrentMessageFromSocket(socket, currentSocketInfo);
```

However, when I pass `currentSocketInfo` to a function by value, then do the exact same reinterpret_cat and assignments, the values are different. (First they're like 0, 1, 0, but after the function call they're like this -252142 <- Not exact number, just similar).

```
void SocketListener::appendCurrentMessageFromSocket(SOCKET socket, SocketInfo socketInfo) {

    auto headerIntPtr = reinterpret_cast<const int32_t*>(socketInfo->header.c_str());

    int32_t index = headerIntPtr[1];
    int32_t type = headerIntPtr[2];
    int32_t tag = headerIntPtr[3];

}
```

---

Here's the `SocketInfo` class, the part related to the question is only the header field:

```
class SocketInfo {
public:
    bool waitingForWholeMessage;
    std::string header;
    std::string body;
    int32_t expectedLength;
};
```

Comment: What is a `SocketInfo`? Could you give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Added the SocketInfo class, sorry I forgot it.

Comment: "when I pass currentSocketInfo to a function by value, then do the exact same reinterpret_cat and assignments,"  Show that code. Also, which compiler are you using and which version?

Comment: `currentSocketInfo.header.reserve(_headerLength);` Use `resize()`, not `reserve()`.

Comment: Instead of 'header.reserve()' you need 'header.resize()'

Comment: Managed to solve it using `resize()`, thank you.

Comment: `socketInfo->header.c_str()` should be `socketInfo.header.c_str()`? because `socketInfo` is an object in `appendCurrentMessageFromSocket()`

Comment: @LordZsolt Hi, is this problem solved? I'd like to know if my answer hit, thanks :p

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show what's inside `recv`, but I assume that it did something similar to `memcpy` some `char`s into `currentSocketInfo.header`.

According to your description, `index`, `type` and `tag` are `0`, `1` and `0`, respectively, so that I can assume that `currentSocketInfo.header` contains `{0,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0}` after executing `recv`.

The next thing is, `string`'s copy construct only copy the "string", which is a `0`-ended `char*`, so it only copy things until a `0` encountered.

Now, with `currentSocketInfo.header` to be `{0,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0}`, the copied `SocketInfo socketInfo` in `SocketListener::appendCurrentMessageFromSocket` has something like `{0}`, which is an empty string.

So, when you do `auto headerIntPtr = reinterpret_cast<const int32_t*>(socketInfo->header.c_str());`, the `headerIntPtr` points to meaningless memory address.

The following codes should produce the same effect of what happened to you:

(P.S. for the sake of simplicity I just change your index to 0, 1 and 2)

```
char c[12] = {0,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0};
std::string s1;
s1.resize(12);
// should be the same effect like `recv`
char* tos1 = const_cast<char*>(s1.c_str());
memcpy(tos1, c, 12);
// end of `recv`

auto p = reinterpret_cast<const int*>(s1.c_str());
int i1 = p[0]; // 0
int i2 = p[1]; // 1
int i3 = p[2]; // 0

std::string s2 = s1;
p = reinterpret_cast<const int*>(s2.c_str());
i1 = p[0]; // 0xcccccc00
i2 = p[1]; // 0xcccccccc
i3 = p[2]; // 0xcccccccc
```

I tested above codes using VS2012 Ultimate